# Why is ViewState not stored on the server by default?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, viewstate

Can someone give me a good reason why ViewState isn't stored on the server by default?

Why not send a small session token in place of ViewState, which can then be mapped to whatever ViewState info is needed on the server, to prevent the whole ViewState being posted back and forwards multiple times.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues with storing the ViewState in memory.

1. If the application recycles, the VS for all anyone using the application is lost.
2. It increases the memory consumption of the application.  This isn't an issue if there are only a few apps hosted on a server; but there are cases when there could be many websites hosted on one box.
3. Scalability; the more active the application, the more VS needs to be stored.  And you can't assume 1-1 (1 user - 1 VS).  A user can have multiple tabs open, can go back, leave tabs inactive, etc... which leads to:
4. How long do you store VS?  Keeping the data encoded on the page ensures that it'll still be there if the user leaves the site open for a while.
5. What happens if you're hosted on a web farm.  We can't guarantee that the user will hit the same machine on each request.

That being said, there are a few solutions:

[Memcached-Viewstate](http://code.google.com/p/memcached-viewstate/) - stores the VS in distributed memory using Memcache.  This isn't ideal - if a server goes down the VS for anyone who had the VS stored to that server is lost, but will allow for application pools to reset without issue.

[SQL-Viewstate](http://weblogs.asp.net/adweigert/archive/2004/03/09/86628.aspx) - stores the VS in a SQL database.  This adds a least 1 DB read and 1 DB write per request.  Again, not ideal, but if the VS is getting unmanagable getting and setting the VS from the database is faster than sending and recieving it over HTTP.

[Filesystem-Viewstate](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20310/Save-ViewState-on-the-File-System) - stores the VS in the filesystem.  It's less expensive than the SQL connection but would require a file server to work in a distributed environment.

Answer (score 4):

Scalability - imagine how much server resources would be needed if a complex WebForms page was viewed by 1M users. Server would need to hold ViewState for at least the duration of the session timeout. Automatic server side cleanup of viewstate would also be problematic - user may be viewing several pages at once so ViewState for all pages would need to be retained.

**Edit**
There are several techniques discussed in [these posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=viewstate%20server) on how to move viewstate to the server. However, before you do that, it would be a good idea to remove unnecessary viewstate from controls / pages which don't need it (e.g. View only / no postback rendering).

I'm guessing now, but when viewstate was designed 10 years or so ago, 1GB RAM on a 32 bit server was about as good as it got, and MS presumably had to think of hosting providers wanting load 100's of apps per server. So bandwidth was probably viewed as cheaper than server Ram and disk storage.

Comment: I would have thought that if ViewState is large enough to cause server memory problems (even with many users) then it would be big enough that it shouldn't be sent over HTTP?

Comment: ViewState is per page 'instance' served. So even if it is just 10kB per page, x 1M users, and each user has 3 pages open we are looking at 30GB ram or disk on the server.

Comment: A million concurrent users is an awful lot though - any server coping with this could need a large amount of ram in any case.

Answer (score 0):

It improves scalability because the server doesn't need to maintain all of that in memory.  It is possible to store the viewstate in session but it's generally not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is using client side view state is that server doesn't know the current state of the page.

If a user is anxious, does multiple (partial) postback on the page, without waiting the response, browser will send out multiple partial postback requests, that each request create a new view state on server side, which will eventually flush out the initial view state in the browser. Finally the user does his last postback, at that time, the inital copy is gone, thus exception is thrown.

Also server side view state impacts server performance and user experience. If a user doesn't interact with the page for a day or a long time, the view state on server will expire. When the user posts back the page later, an exception is thrown.

For instance I watch youtube video of length 40 minutes. Yesterday I watched the first half, didn't close the tab but hiberated my computer. Today I continue watchig the last half, and post back something, the page will get errored out if the view state is in server and expired.